# Python - Relative import

Tags: python, import

I am developing a Python program where it manages and runs modules ( .py python files ) which can be added by users and are imported into the main program ( foo.py ) by using import function. Here's the directory structure

```
Foo/
    foo.py #Main script. Imports ouput.py, core.py and bar.py when needed.
    src/
        __init__.py
        output.py #Output functions required by bar.py and foo.py
        core.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        bar.py #Needs output.py
```

I can import in foo.py by using

```
from src.output import *
```

But the problem I face is that when I try to import output.py from bar.py by using

```
from ..src.output import *
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

I am putting the files in different directories as it makes it easier for different programmers to code it separately and I definitely need a folder 'modules' or something where .py module files can be added and its functionality be used in bar.py

And please tell me if I am doing this wrong. And feel free to suggest a better way to do it.

Thank You.

Comment: imports are all relative to the top level. src.output looks in Foo/src/output. ..src.output tries to go above Foo at which point the library breaks since it can't import outside of the project. You should add the modules you want to some other directory structure or change your classpath

Comment: Aah I see, When I import from foo.bar .. is not required. Thanks. But is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because `Foo` has no `__init__.py`, so it is not considered a package.

Each period in a relative import refers to a package. When you do

```
from ..src.output import *
```

In `bar.py`, the first period refers to the current package, `modules`. The second period refers to the package above that, `Foo`. Since `Foo` isn't actually a package, you get an error.

P.S. Wildcard imports are frowned upon. Especially when you're importing from a distantly related package like this, I'd try to refactor it into explicit imports.

Comment: Thank You. But can you kindly be little more clear on explicit imports ? Maybe give an example ?

Comment: @GrimReaper explicit import means that you should not use `import *` but rather explicitly state what you are importing, like `from mymodule import myfunc, myclass`

Comment: Thank You. Should any modifications be made to my directory structure ?

Comment: So would it be so wrong to give `Foo` an ` __init__.py` file to make the relative import work (even though it's not really a package)?